# Animate view from top to bottom till a certain view becomes invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have 3 Linear Layouts say A, B, C(from top to bottom). I want A&B to translate/animate down **till B becomes invisible**. **"C" remains at its own place** eg.

AAAAAAA

AAAAAAA

BBBBBBB

BBBBBBB

CCCCCCC

CCCCCCC

**becomes**

AAAAAAA

AAAAAAA

CCCCCCC

CCCCCCC

NOTE: **A&B should move down together** & finally stop till B becomes invisible. **"A" still remains visible**.I used translate animation.

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="??%" />
```

I'm confused what my android:toYDelta="??" be. I took 80% but it reacts differently on different phones

Comment: If someone can suggest me a more appropriate title for the question it would be very kind.

Comment: I think your explanation is not enough. I don't really understand what you're actually trying to do. Maybe some illustration (drawing) that could explain your issue a bit better?

Comment: @BartoszLipinski : Is it better now??